# Struts2 Validation using XML not working?

Tags: java, struts2

I'm trying to use Struts2 validation using XML to check various fields entered by Customer. My `struts.xml` extends `struts-default`, and I have a extremely simple action class `TestAction` which extends `ActionSupport`, but it is not working.

If anyone is able to help me see what I lack, I would be extremely grateful.

Here's what I have:

**CustomerAction-validation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="customerName">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>Required</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="addCustomer" class="com.yell.hibu.action.CustomerAction"
            method="execute">
            <interceptor-ref name="validation"/> 
             <param name="excludeMethods">  
                    input,back,cancel,browse  
                </param>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">
                    image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
                </param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/registration.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Here I have Registration.jsp for only 1 field

```
<s:form action="addCustomer" id="register-form" method="post"  validate="true" theme="xhtml" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<s:actionerror/>
<s:fielderror/>
<s:textfield name="customer.customerName" label="Customer Name:" cssClass="tooltip"  title="Max 10 characters allowed." maxlength="10"/>
```

Comment: Not enough information to help. Where is the validation file deployed to? What happens/doesn't happen? Does the action have the appropriate getter/setter?

Comment: What is the code for class `TestAction`?

Comment: try this link, hope it  solves your problem http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/ValidationInterceptor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
<interceptor-ref name="validation"/>
```

is self-closed, then the

```
<param name="excludeMethods">  
        input,back,cancel,browse  
</param>
```

will never be read.

`Validation Interceptor` should run *after* `Params Interceptor`, as shown in the [examples from the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/validation-interceptor.html).

Again, according to the documentation,

> This interceptor is often one of the last (or second to last) interceptors applied in a stack, as it assumes that all values have already been set on the action.

Then, try to do like this:

```
<action name="addCustomer" class="com.yell.hibu.action.CustomerAction" 
        method="execute">

    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>

    <interceptor-ref name="validation"> 
        <param name="excludeMethods">  
            input,back,cancel,browse  
        </param>
    </interceptor-ref>

    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
            <param name="allowedTypes">
                image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
            </param>
    </interceptor-ref>

    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/registration.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If it does not work, post your JSP and Action too.

Hope that helps